# C++ break statement alternative

Tags: c++

Sorry for the "stupid" question, I'm not familiar with C++. I have this:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {

    if (ar[i] == 1) {

        printf ("Wrong.\n");
        break;
    }
    else {

        printf ("Correct.\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I do this without a break `statement`? Someone suggested me to use a `while` loop. Will that work?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense, it will break out of the loop if `ar[i] == 1` ***and*** break out of the loop if `ar[i] != 1`. Can you please elaborate on the actual problem you try to solve? Preferably show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried as well.

Comment: Yeah, what are you trying to do? There's no looping going on in this code.

Comment: `i= n;` instead of `break;` to force the exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goto` is an alternative.

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {

    if (ar[i] == 1) {

        printf ("Wrong.\n");
        goto endofthefor;
    }
    else {

        printf ("Correct.\n");
        goto endofthefor;
    }
}
endofthefor: ;
```

If you don't want to use `goto`, either, using a flag to break the loop is a way.

```
{
    int breaktheloop = 0;
    for (i=0; !breaktheloop && i<n; (!breaktheloop) && (i++)) {

        if (ar[i] == 1) {

            printf ("Wrong.\n");
            breaktheloop = 1; continue;
        }
        else {

            printf ("Correct.\n");
            breaktheloop = 1; continue;
        }
    }
}
```

`(!breaktheloop) && (i++)` means `if(!breaktheloop)i++;`. I used this because we cannot put a statement there in the `for`.

Comment: int flag? This is C++ question

Comment: @Slava: So? `int` works just as well as `bool`. I don't complain about his non-padded parenthesis and operators either. ;)

Comment: @DevSolar readability is the main target when you write program, `bool` shows intention and avoid unnecessary errors. There is a reason why `bool` was added to the language

Comment: @DevSolar but shouldn't we be trying to help? If best practice is to use a `bool` in C++ then use a `bool`. And if code is poorly-formatted and it takes 5 seconds to fix, fix it (I already put in an edit for it, trying to practice what I preach). Otherwise, SO becomes a conglomeration of poor, messy questions and misguided answers.

Comment: @dwanderson: For one, [`<stdbool.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) is available for C as well. And while I admit `bool` is "cleaner", I don't see anything "misguided" in the code here. I'd argue against the `goto` in the first half long before I'd raise an eyebrow at an integer flag...

Comment: `goto`? Immeadite downvote, sorry.

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn't saying `goto` is a good idea here either.

Answer (score 4):

The code below has the same effect (even though I doubt this is what you intended):

```
i= 0;
if (n > 0)
{
    if (ar[0] == 1) {
        printf ("Wrong.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("Correct.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't have the same effect. What if `n <= 0`?

Comment: @MikeCAT: yep, fixed.

Comment: `i` will be `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Please remove `i= 1;`

Comment: Why on the earth do you refuse to match the result? http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LdUao1ZAhlmajkuS

Comment: @MikeCAT: open your eyes.

Comment: **You** open your eyes and see the execution result.

Comment: @MikeCAT And ? What's the problem ?

Comment: Putting `i= 1;` may reduce the preformance silghtly, and also it make the behavior different from the original code.

Comment: @MikeCAT Not putting `i= 1;` does change the behavior.

Comment: How come? If you propose that not putting `i= 1;` changes the behavior, please explain what is the original behavior and what is the changed behavior.

Comment: @MikeCAT: that of a for loop.

Comment: Do see the [execution result](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fDqe0XuAkohzr0gQ). The value of `i` after executing the piece of code differs from the "original" code and "with" `i= 1;` code for `i = -1, n = 1, ar[0] = -1` case for example.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yep, all my apologies, `break` bypasses loop incrementation. -1 for me.

Comment: Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose do you want to avoid a break statement? The first alternative I could think of is a [goto statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto)

```
int main()
{
//declare 'ar' array
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {

        if (ar[i] == 1) {

            printf ("Wrong.\n");
            goto someLabel;
        }
        else {

            printf ("Correct.\n");
            goto someLabel;
        }
    }

    someLabel:
    printf("Hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `goto` should be considered a viable alternative to `break`.

Comment: @crashmstr: `goto` statement is OK as alternative, but not if I want to make something of more readable. But I didn't specify that it should be **better** or **wrong** alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a while loop like:

```
int i = 0;
bool found = false;
while(i<n && !found) {
    if (ar[i] == 1) {
       printf ("Wrong.\n");
       found = true;
    } else {
      printf ("Correct.\n");
      found = true;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This won't do exact the same thing as the original code because `i++;` will be  executed even after finding.

Comment: That is correct. But the original code does not make any sense. It is unclear what the task is.

Comment: @bbakiu where should I put `i++`? BTW It's a generic question, what should I do as alternative to `break`. Also, `++i` is bad to use - you should use a prefix (not postfix) `++`, as `i` is just an int.

Comment: In stead of break; you should create another condition which is the found variable I have created in my code. The i++ should be in the end of the while loop (before the closing parentheses). And you should remove the else part if you are only trying to make sure that array does NOT contain number 1. Related to i++ or ++i it is irrelevant to your use case.

Comment: @bbakiu: 1) talk with the correct terminology. `found` traditionally in this case is called flag. 2) You didn't understand. `i` is just an `int`, so you should use a prefix, **not** a postfix ++; it isn't adequate in this case. Then it will be: `++i`.

Comment: Ok @DrProgrammer. Next time write meaningful code!

Comment: @bbakiu edit your answer?

Comment: Dear @DrProgrammer, you can try the code and I can ensure you that in the while loop it is irrelevant if it is prefix or postfix. But in the for loop it makes a difference, so you are correct. My code is not wrong, that is why no edit is needed.

Comment: @bbakiu you don't seem to me familiar with postfix/prefix increment. The prefix `++i` and suffix `i++` operators affect the order in which the statement is evaluated. With the prefix `++i`, the value of `i` is incremented, and that is what is used. But with the suffix i++, the original value of i is used, and then it is incremented for anything following that line. Rather it's relevant, because `i` **is an int**.  It is typical that a postfix operator will be worse on performance because you have to create another copy before doing the increment, that's why.

Comment: @DrProgrammer I am quite familiar with prefix and suffix. You can make clear what you want to achieve by your code, and you will get a correct solution. As for prefix/suffix here are some useful links so you can see what is the difference:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html  http://www.mycodingland.com/2015/09/what-is-difference-between-increment-statements.html

Comment: I know what is the difference. What I'm saying is that in this case you should use a prefix increment. It's more adequate in this code. It isn't just about syntax.